# Laravel downgrade 5.2.19 - 5.1.*

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, downgrade

I had Laravel Framework version 5.2.19. After changing in composer.json `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"` and deleting vendor folder I tried `composer install` ,but `php artisan --version` it's still 5.2.19. While installing where was no any errors and warnings. And no packages are installed. 
If I try to `composer update`,while `php artisan clear-compiled` it will output

```
 Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.1.9 requires symfony/css-selector 2.7.* -> 
    satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[2.7.x-dev, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, 
    v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, 
    v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4,
    v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9] but these conflict with your 
    requirements or minimum-stability.
```

And if i try to update css-selector by adding in require-dev `"symfony/css-selector": "~2.7.*"`. Other versions of css-selector also tried(upper, lower).
**How to downgrade properly?**

Comment: You need to update composer not install it. Try `composer update`.

Comment: updated question, css-selector issue

Comment: Change the symfony/css-selector version to 2.7.* and try again.

Comment: updated question, i tried to spell it in different ways but still same issue with css-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your constraints in `composer.json` match those that shipped with [the Laravel 5.1 project skeleton](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/composer.json). As per the discussion above, you can remove the `symfony/css-selector` requirement as that was introduced in Laravel 5.2. Then run `composer update` to pull in your new dependencies.

Comment: It works, but i received while > php artisan optimize `[BadMethodCallException] Method auth does not exist.Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1.`, but after few changes in Model, Routes and Controller it works fine. Thanks!